# Unexpected metadata type found in active-android

Tags: android, database, gradle, compiler-errors, omr

For a unknown reason Android Studio Fail to build my Project .
First time it show me

```
  Error:Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
  Could not load module metadata from C:\Users\nirzo\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.36\descriptors\com.michaelpardo\activeandroid\3.1.0-SNAPSHOT\c5bb972da5c05fbf59bb87e44d69a746\descriptor.bin

  Unexpected metadata type found.
```

When I clean the Project for second time it show me the below error again . I also try Invalidated Caches

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT.
  Required by:
  project :app

> Could not resolve com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT.
> Could not load module metadata from C:\Users\nirzo\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.36\descriptors\com.michaelpardo\activeandroid\3.1.0-SNAPSHOT\c5bb972da5c05fbf59bb87e44d69a746\descriptor.bin
```

But the Project is perfectly running on my other PC

I really don't understand the problem and the reason of it .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

the solution is very simple you dont have to uninstall android studio. the issue ussually happens because you gradles cannot load data in the  metadata folder or you have multiple data folder in the gradle file.
follow the following steps
1.go to  "C:\Users\pc.gradle\caches\modules-2\"
2.delete any metadata folder availabe.
3.return to android studio and rebuild your project ensuring that you have internet connections
5.wait for the gradle to download some files and sync then
6.everything should wwork well after doing that

Answer (score 2):

delete the .gradle file. Connect to the internet. Sync gradle.. Thats it.

I fixed that error by deleting the gradle file completely located inside the

```
local disk: C:\Users\user\.gradle
```

Answer (score 0):

1.go to "C:\Users\pc.gradle\caches\modules-2"
2.delete any metadata folder availabe.
3.return to android studio and rebuild your project ensuring that you have internet connections
4.wait for the gradle to download some files and sync then

everything should wwork well after doing that
the frist solu but clearly